# How can i deserialize before saving in REST Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer

`users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, required=False)`

Now this expects the users to be list `[1,2,3]`

Now i am sending users as complete list of user objects like `[user1, user2]`.

I can make that list of ids in frontend with JS. but i want some function in serilaizer where i can post as complete objects but system makes it list of ids.

I used Complete `UsersSerializer` instead of PrimaryKey but then either it would try to write user object with it or not write at all. I want only to write relations for many to many

Answer (score 0):

Use `UsersSerializer`

```
users = UsersSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

and overwrite `validate` method in the serializer. Retrieve all users instances from users ids list  and re-assign it to `data['users']`. So, when you selerializer calls create/update method, in the validated data dict you will have users instances instead of users id.

```
def validate(self, data):
    request = self.context['request']
    user    = request.user
    print "dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    users_ids = request.DATA.getlist('users')
    users = User.objects.filter(id__in=users_id)
    data['users'] = users
    return data
```